# IN operation between 2 groups SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to do something like this

```
select * 
from table1 a
where (select column2 
       from table1 
       where column1 = a.column1) in (select distinct mastercolumn2 
                                      from mastertable)
```

but it is throwing this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error is clear, you have more than 1 row.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the results you'd like to get for this sample

Comment: i just want to know is there any way to do wat i want to do searching for items between 2 groups

Comment: You are already selecting from Table1. Change the Where to `Where column2 in (select distinct mastercolumn2 from mastertable)`

Comment: Learn how to ask question . https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @HoaxGod It will be better to show tables structure, sample data and the expected results, in this way you helpus to help you, and you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
select * 
from table1 a
where exists (
  select 1
  from table1 i
  where i.column1=a.column1
    and i.column2 in (
      select mastercolumn2 
      from mastertable
      )
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BRX68307

returns:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

given this test setup:

```
create table table1 (column1 int, column2 int)
insert into table1 values
 (1,1),(1,2)
,(2,2)
,(3,1),(3,3)

create table mastertable (mastercolumn2 int)
insert into mastertable values (2)
```

Comment: I think he try `Col1 = Col2 AND Col2 IN ()`

Comment: @Sami I see what you thought in your comment and answer, but I disagree... thanks though!

Comment: Yup, we just suggest solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 
where column2 in (select distinct mastercolumn2 from mastertable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a
WHERE  
    Column2 = Column1 --(select column2 from table1 where column1=a.column1)
    AND  Column2 IN (SELECT distinct mastercolumn2 from mastertable) --in(select distinct mastercolumn2 from mastertable)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the `IN` operator takes a single value on the left side, and a list of values on the right side. You can't use it for two lists.

**Correct:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Column IN(Val1, Val2[,...Valn])

SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Value IN(Column1, Column2[,...Columnn])
```

**Incorrect:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Column1, Column2) IN(Val1, Val2[,...Valn])
```

Second, the code you posted could be simplified to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a
WHERE Column2 IN (SELECT mastercolumn2 
                  FROM mastertable)
```